# How to get an array in asp (Server side) to javascript?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Hi i have float array in server side i want to take this array to javascript how do i do this?

I'm using c#

Comment: C# and asp-classic? maybe asp.Net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example by registering the values using clientscript:

On your code behind:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  foreach(var f in myFloats)
     Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("myFloats", f.ToString());
}
```

You see a more complete example here:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/92600/How-to-pass-ASP-NET-server-side-array-to-client-si

Hope it helps.

Comment: Read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: @shiplu.mokadd.im I answered this question from my cellphone. Makes it a bit hard to write sample code. I've edited the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As a simple exsample :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Convert your float array to below 
        var list = new List<string>() { "'1.00'", "'2.00'", "'3.00'", "'4.00'" };
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arr ", string.Join("," , list.ToArray()));
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "excute", "<script language='javascript'>alert(arr);</script>");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/pini_dayan/archive/2009/03/12/convert-objects-to-json-in-c-using-javascriptserializer.aspx

then

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/

Comment: The links I shared have plenty of code already. If you are too lazy to read them, I can't help you.

Comment: read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers